# Display the month in QCalendarWidget

Tags: qt

I use a QCalendarWidget for my application. I would like to display the month and the year in the Calendar but by default, I have just the number of the week, and it's not useful.

Is it possible to display these parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set setNavigationBarVisible (true);

Answer (score 0):

The [navigationBarVisible](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html#navigationBarVisible-prop) property is what you are looking for. Also you can look through [this example](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/widgets-calendarwidget.html) to learn more about calendar widget.